# Separate /var partition is still getting full

Tags: ssd, log

The `/var` partition on my intel SSD is getting full. Even though I have increased it size to 100GB, which is quite ridiculous.

The `kern.log` and `syslog`. files are each 31.7 GB big.

1. how can I remove the files? Because just deleting them is denied.
2. What is the cause and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: It'd be helpful to know what exactly is getting full.  Provide us the output of `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /var/ | sort -h` as an edit for us to get some guidance on what exactly is taking up space.  This'll help us to start narrowing down the files using up all the space.

Comment: What brand/model system? Have you updated UEFI & SSD's firmware? Some brands have run away log files like this and need boot parameters: Asus x555u w/o pci=nomsi - space issue on drive and runaway log files filling drive
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2327103&page=3

Comment: the kern.log and syslog. files are each 31.7 GB big

Comment: As requested the list of files:<                                                                              pre>4,0K /var/local
4,0K /var/mail
4,0K /var/metrics
4,0K /var/opt
16K /var/lost+found
52K /var/spool
52K /var/tmp
252K /var/snap
916K /var/crash
1,5M /var/webmin
2,6M /var/backups
48M /var/cache
1,9G /var/lib
64G /var/log
66G /var/
</pre>

Comment: @Asaf If you edit, please don't just change one word but do a thorough edit, so please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1107270/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own edits in the future... **;-)**